# Ordering multi-indexed pandas dataframe on two levels, with different criteria for each level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the dataframe `df_counts`, constructed as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "word" : ["AA", "AC", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BB", "BB"],
    "letter1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "letter2": ["A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B"]
})
df_counts = df2[["word", "letter1", "letter2"]].groupby(["letter1", "letter2"]).count()
```

Output:

[image]

What I would like to do from here, is to order first by `letter1` totals, so the rows for `letter1 == "B"` appear first (there are four words starting with `B`, vs only three with `A`), and then ordered within each grouping of `letter1` by the values in the `word` column.

So the final output should be:

```
                 word
letter1 letter2 
      B       B     3
              A     1
      A       C     2
              A     1
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a complex sorting order, it's always easy to use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
# minor sorting order first, major one last
# - to inverse the order
order = np.lexsort([-df_counts['word'],
                    -df_counts.groupby('letter1')['word'].transform('sum')])

out = df_counts.iloc[order]
```

The pandas equivalent would be:

```
(df_counts
 .assign(total=df_counts.groupby('letter1')['word'].transform('sum'))
 .sort_values(by=['total', 'word'], ascending=False)
 .drop(columns='total')
)
```

Output:

```
                 word
letter1 letter2      
B       B           3
        A           1
A       C           2
        A           1
```

Answer (score 1):

use sort_index with index name and ascending pair as True or False

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "word" : ["AA", "AC", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BB", "BB"],
    "letter1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "letter2": ["A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B"]
})

df_counts = df2[["word", "letter1", "letter2"]].groupby(["letter1", "letter2"]).count()

print(df_counts.index)
print(df_counts.sort_index(level=["letter1","letter2"],ascending=[False,False]))
```

output:

```
                    word
letter1 letter2      
B       B           3
        A           1
A       C           2
        A           1
```